# sparql exclude multiple type hierarchy

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

In dbpedia I select some pages with label starting 'A'. Here I'm using additional filter by subject to narrow the set. In original version there are another conditions (result set is much bigger)

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX purl: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/page/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT DISTINCT 
   ?pageType
WHERE
{ 
   {
       ?page rdfs:label ?label .
       ?page a ?pageType .
       ?page <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Banking> .
   }

   FILTER ( strstarts(str(?pageType), 'http://dbpedia.org/ontology') )
}

LIMIT 1000
```

[sparql results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+skos%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2004%2F02%2Fskos%2Fcore%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+purl%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fpage%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dc%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbr%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+%0D%0A+++%3FpageType%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B+%0D%0A+++%7B%0D%0A+++++++%3Fpage+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+.%0D%0A+++++++%3Fpage+a+%3FpageType+.%0D%0A+++++++%3Fpage+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fsubject%3E+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCategory%3ABanking%3E+.%0D%0A+++%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A+++FILTER+%28+strstarts%28str%28%3FpageType%29%2C+%27http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%27%29+%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ALIMIT+1000%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Here I select only page types to be clear with rest of the question.
This is the whole set. Now I want to exclude some pages. Exclude all agents (persons, organization etc):

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX purl: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/page/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT DISTINCT 
   ?pageType
WHERE
{ 
   {
       ?page rdfs:label ?label .
       ?page a ?pageType .
       ?page <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Banking> .

       MINUS { ?page a dbo:Agent }
   }

   FILTER ( strstarts(str(?pageType), 'http://dbpedia.org/ontology') )
}

LIMIT 1000
```

[The result.](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20skos%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2004%2F02%2Fskos%2Fcore%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20purl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fpage%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dc%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%3FpageType%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fpage%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fpage%20a%20%3FpageType%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fpage%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fsubject%3E%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCategory%3ABanking%3E%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20MINUS%20%7B%20%3Fpage%20a%20dbo%3AAgent%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20strstarts%28str%28%3FpageType%29%2C%20%27http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%27%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ALIMIT%201000%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Ok. Then I want to exclude more types, for example Written_Work. I tried different approaches, but unabled to find the correct one.

This returns nothing:

```
WHERE
{ 
   {
       ?page rdfs:label ?label .
       ?page a ?pageType .
       ?page <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Banking> .

       MINUS { ?page a dbo:Agent }
       MINUS { ?page a dbo:WrittenWork }

   }
```

This is like no filter is set:

```
WHERE
{ 
   {
       ?page rdfs:label ?label .
       ?page a ?pageType .
       ?page <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Banking> .

       MINUS { ?page a dbo:Agent, dbo:WrittenWork }
   }
```

The question is:
**what way should I go to exclude pages of certain types (direct and superclass)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It look's like this is working answer (how to exclude multiple of types)

```
  {
       ?page purl:subject ?id .
       ?page a ?pageType .

       FILTER NOT EXISTS {
        ?page a/rdfs:subClassOf* ?skipClasses .
        FILTER(?skipClasses in (dbo:Agent, dbo:Place, dbo:Work))
       }

   }
```

In this example all dbo:Agents, db:Places, dbo:Works will be filtered out.

Comment: Replacing `MINUS { ?page a dbo:Agent }` with `FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?page a dbo:Agent }` may also work.

Comment: Yes, it works for single type exclusion. In my case it doesn't help